# PHPExcel export images issue when hide or delete the column

Tags: php, phpexcel

Firstly i want to show screenshots about the issue.

#### Exported Default Excel

[image]

#### Hiding A Column

A column hidden but images still showing.

[image]

#### Delete A Column

Titles and content deleted but images still showing

[image]

I want to export all products with images. But images in cell doesnt hiding or deleting actions.

**My tried codes:**

```
$column = "A{$i}";          
$gdImage = imagecreatefromjpeg('img/hello_world.jpg');
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing();
$objDrawing->setName('Sample image');
$objDrawing->setDescription('Sample image');
$objDrawing->setImageResource($gdImage);
$objDrawing->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_JPEG);
$objDrawing->setMimeType(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);
$objDrawing->setWidth(50);
$objDrawing->setHeight(50);
$objDrawing->setCoordinates($column);
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);
```

#### Updated

I found the solution with ms excel that images have `move and size with cells` option. If i can set this option `move and size with cells` from PHPExcel, issue will solve.

Any ideas?

Comment: Images are "overlaid", they are not cell content; so hiding a column or row doesn't affect the images.... how would you do what you're trying to do in MS Excel itself?

Comment: @MarkBaker I have working samples on other application about this issue. I didnt understand your last sentence. So what should i do?

Comment: What I mean is, if you were to create that spreadsheet using MS Excel itself (not PHPExcel); what would happen to the images if you hid/deleted column A?

Comment: Basically, this is nothing to do with PHPExcel, but with MS Excel itself

Comment: I tried with MS Excel, not working too :) But i have working sample. Can you check this file? https://www.dropbox.com/s/qtkinig3cl6z88w/test.xls?dl=0 When you hide the A column, you will see. This excel file is exported from the application. What do you think?

Comment: I haven't got a clue

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker for interest.

Comment: @MarkBaker I found the solution on ms excel. Image haves `move and size with cells` option from properties. How can i set the image option `move and size with cells`? Do you have any idea?

Comment: Not without trying to trace what that option is called in the format specifications, which could take some time.... it's not the most intuitive documentation in the world